# How to rewrite equations of random vectors in terms of individual component random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

I'm trying to understand the Expectation Maximization algorithm, using the [tutorial by Sean Borman](https://www.lri.fr/%7Esebag/COURS/EM_algorithm.pdf).

To state the context of my problem, I'll quote his original words from the tutorial if I don't quite understand it.

> Let $X$ be random vector which results from a parameterized family.
> (Page 9, section 3.1, first sentence)

and $Z$ is the unobserved data, $\theta$ is the unknown parameter, $\theta_n$ is the value of $\theta$ in the n-th iteration.

The tutorial later derived the update for $\theta$: (Page 9, equation 15)

$$
\begin{align*}
\theta_{n+1} \\
&= \underset{\theta}{\mathrm{argmax}}\{
\Sigma_z{P(z\vert{X, \theta_n})\mathrm{ln}P(X,z\vert\theta)}
\} \\
&= \underset{\theta}{\mathrm{argmax}}\{
E_{Z|{X, \theta_n}}{\{\mathrm{ln}P(X,z\vert\theta)\}}
\}
\end{align*}
$$

Question 1 (easy): To be precise on the notation, the lowercase $z$ in the conditional expression $E_{Z|{X,\theta_n}}{\{\mathrm{ln}P(X,z\vert\theta)\}}$ should be uppercase, right?

Context for question 2: I have $m$ observed data points (not necessarily one dimensional), $x_i, i=1..m$, and a parameterized model, (e.g. $x_i$ is generated from a Gaussian Mixture with unknown mixing proportions and means. Just an example, the answer needs not to be about this specific choice of model).

Question 2.1: How can I rewrite the above update for $\theta$, in terms of $X_i$s and $Z_i$s ($i = 1..m$), which are random variables for each observed and unobserved data? (I assume that the $X$ in the tutorial stands for a collection of observations, and "let $X = (X_1, .., X_m)$, and $Z = (Z_1, .., Z_m)$" would appear somewhere in the formulation).

Question 2.2: What usuall assumptions I need to make about $X_i$ and $Z_i$ in order for the rewrite to work (e.g. $(X_i, Z_i)$ need to be conditionally independent to $(X_j, Z_j)$ for all $i \ne j$ conditioned on all $\theta$s)?

I didn't find any good tutorial/lecture slides that touches the question 2, they usually jump straight to the concrete expressions of the conditional expression, with something like $E = \underset{i} \Pi {p_ie^{x_i-\mu}}$ (the expression is made up, to make the point clear).

Really appreciate if someone can give a formal formulation of the above two euations in terms of individual random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The E step is to compute the Q-function, which is the expectation of the complete data log likelihood. You are right that z should be capitalized. However, in my textbook and the literature it seems to be lowercase. We use the fact that $(x_i,z_i)$ are i.i.d., i.e. the pairs must be independent of one another. Then the likelihood factorizes into the product of their individual likelihoods.

E-step:

$$\begin{split}Q(\theta) &= \mathbb E\left[\ln p(X, Z|\theta)|\theta_n\right] \\&=
\mathbb E\left[\ln \prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i,Z_i|\theta)|\theta_n\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\sum \ln p(X_i, Z_i|\theta)|\theta_n\right]\\
&= \sum _{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\ln p(X_i, Z_i|\theta)|\theta_n\right]\\
&= \sum _{i=1}^n \sum_{z_i} p(z_i|\theta_n,X_i)\ln p(X_i,z_i|\theta)\end{split}$$

Q is now a function of $\theta$, so the M step is to maximize it w.r.t. $\theta$.

M-step:

$$\theta^{(n+1)}=\arg\max_\theta{Q(\theta)}$$

Comment: Thanks. This is far more elegant than my own derivation.